# Tags: iCal vs. Calendar, Address Book vs. Contacts

Tags: discussion, tags

The definition of the [ical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ical) tag is:

> Apple's calendar application, bundled with every Mac OS X install

Whereas the [calendar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) tag is:

> A calendar is visual representation of time, often charted by months, weeks, or days. Often, a calendar app will help one organize events on a calendar, and sometimes provide alerts or reminders as well.

However, with the advent of Mountain Lion (and, indeed, even with iOS for a while now), `Calendar` is the name of the `iCal` application.  I imagine Apple's intent is to phase out the use of the name `iCal` as it homogenizes the platforms.

The same is true of the [address-book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address-book) tag:

> Apple's built-in contacts manager software for Mac OS X.

vs. the [contacts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts) tag:

> Information stored on a computer about various methods to contact a person, such as e-mail, various chat networks, telephone, physical address, etc.

`Contacts` is now the name of the `Address Book` application.

---

I imagine that simply merging the tags isn't a workable solution, as questions previously tagged with [calendar](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar) or [contacts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts) aren't guaranteed to actually be referring to the formerly-named `iCal` or `Address Book` applications.

Going forward, however, new users on Mountain Lion and iOS devices will probably be less and less familiar with the terms `iCal` and `Address Book`.  How should the community address this with the tags?

Comment: I believe the solution is to develop a time machine so all users are familiar with all the old technologies and terms. Apple ][ Forever!

Answer (score 3):

The same way it has for [mail](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) and [mail.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail.app).

We create [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app) and [calendar.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar.app). The tag could be used for both iOS and OS X.

I don't think a synonym should be set between for [ical](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ical) => [calendar.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calendar.app) and [address-book](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/address-book) => [contacts.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contacts.app), since Mountain Lion is not the majority OS, yet.

Comment: The .app tags seem sensible, but I don't really see the problem in making a synonym straight away.

Comment: It's worth pointing out the workaround, which is to use two tags.  (mac + calendar) almost certainly refers to whatever the mac calendar app is called, regardless if it's "iCal" or "Calendar".

Comment: I'm going to necropost here by saying that there's also [tag:apple-watch] and [tag:apple-watch.app]